# Mapping FileHelpers to multiple output properties

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm using the C# FileHelpers library to efficiently parse large delimited files into validation objects.

However, I'd like to be able to map a single input file column to more than one output class property, but can't find an obvious way to achieve this. I've looked at ITransformable, but I don't want to map to yet another object to cut down on memory during the operation, and I've looked at the DynamicFieldBuilder/DynamicClassBuilder objects, but these seem to only allow me to describe what's in the input file, not what should be in the output instance.

I am trying to avoid having to load the file twice or do some kind of object-to-object mapping after the fact.

Input File Example:

```
ColumnA|ColumnB
Foo|Baz
```

Output Class Example:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string ColumnA_One;
    public string ColumnA_Two;
    public string ColumnB_One;
    public string ColumnB_Two;
}
```

Comment: You could do this if you created an enum and for the extraneous columns create a separate enum as well does this make sense the enum would hold the column order and if different files share that coulunm but in a different order.. then index or access them by ordinal position casting them of course by (int)then enum field name look at my example below

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I want a single input file like the example above to result in an instance of FooBar where both ColumnA_One and ColumnA_Two are equal to 'Foo' and ColumnB_One and ColumnB_Two are equal to "Baz".

Comment: yes but looking at CollumnA_One for example what are the field names that you are wanting.. send me or show me a list of all the fields and I can construct an enum example for you.. it would be nice to know if the data that you are using has a Delimiter as well for my example my 5 different files share the enum construct and have a comma as the delim

Comment: Those are the field names. Enums are not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the duplicate columns with the [`FieldIgnored` attribute](http://www.filehelpers.com/FileHelpers.FieldIgnoredAttribute.html) and use the [`AfterReadRecord` event](http://www.filehelpers.com/FileHelpers.AfterReadRecordHandler.html) to fill them.

```
class Program
{
    [DelimitedRecord("|")]
    public class FooBar
    {
        public string ColumnA_One;       
        [FieldIgnored]
        public string ColumnA_Two;        

        public string ColumnB_One;        
        [FieldIgnored]
        public string ColumnB_Two;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(FooBar));
        engine.AfterReadRecord += engine_AfterReadRecord;
        FooBar[] records = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt") as FooBar[];
    }

    static void engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        FooBar fooBar = e.Record as FooBar;
        fooBar.ColumnA_Two = fooBar.ColumnA_One;
        fooBar.ColumnB_Two = fooBar.ColumnB_One;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, and we tried this approach, but unfortunately it's not performant because you end up doing the processing twice; once to read the record in, and again after each row to copy the data over to the other column.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but we ended up patching FileHelpers to include a [FieldRawValue] property and, by convention, we populate any properties with this attribute with the untransformed value from the previous column.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum DataFields
    {
        Action = 0,
        CRC = 1,
        Desc = 2,
        Group = 3,
        Name = 4,
        Sell = 5,
        EffDate = 6,
        Whse = 7,
        Whse2 = 8,
        Whse3 = 9,
        Casepack = 10,
        LDU = 11,
        Cube = 12,
        Item = 13,
        UPC = 14,
        Cost = 15,
        Markup = 16,
        OldSell = 17,
        Avail = 18,
        Substitute = 19,
        Poll = 20
    }//enum DataFields

    /// <summary>
    /// This will hold the ordinal position of the NameFields within the datafile
    /// </summary>
    enum NameFields
    {
        Code = 0,
        Abrv = 1,
        Name = 2,
        Count = 3
    }//enum NameFields

    /// <summary>
    /// This will hold the ordinal position of the values when populating the history table
    /// </summary>
    enum HistoryFields
    {
        CRC = 0,
        EffDate = 1,
        OldSell = 2,
        Sell = 3
    }//enum HistoryFields
    #endregion
```